# input[range] progress workaround in chrome not working when selecting value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reactjs, input

I'm trying to implement a range input that changes the color before the handle. Here is a function that is called everytime I change the value of the range:

```
 updateProgress (val = this.range.value) {
    const percent = Math.ceil(
      ((val - this.range.min) /
        (this.range.max - this.range.min)) * 100
    );

    this.range.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff ${
      percent
    }%,#363439 ${
      percent
    }%,#363439 100%)`;

  }
```

here is the full working example https://jsfiddle.net/a2rLfu6a/

Now if you just listen to the music on the example it works, even though you can see that the gradient isn't always following the handle - sometimes it is "late".

If you try to click somewhere on the range to seek a particular time, it will seek the right moment in the audio, but the whole track will goes white. Why and how I can I solve this?

Comment: isn't that because of the focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean but removing:

```
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
```

does not render the track white when you click on it.

Comment: lol it looks simple and obvious put like that. Yes basically it was focus!

Comment: sometimes it's just the simple things that we miss after spending a long time working on more complex issues :)

Comment: Yes thanks! Another look from someone else on your code is the best thing :)